# Why did SQL Server renumber all of my primary key IDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Server 2012 database that contains information about lectures. I needed to do some work to this, including renaming the primary key field, which is an identity. Having read up about this, it seemed straightforward enough, and I did the changes.

Afterwards, I found out that SQL Server had renumbered all of the IDs, filling in the gaps. However, it hadn't updated the other tables that had foreign key relations with this table, resulting in my data becoming totally corrupt.

For example, here is a sample of the data from before the change (old stuff, from the early days)...

```
ID  Date                    SpeakerID
9   2005-03-24 00:00:00.000 3
11  2005-05-16 00:00:00.000 26
12  2005-10-24 00:00:00.000 55
13  2005-11-13 00:00:00.000 26
14  2006-01-10 00:00:00.000 1
15  2006-01-09 00:00:00.000 2
```

As you can see, we don't have a lecture with an ID of 10.

After I renamed the primary key, SQL Server renumbered the lectures, closing up the gaps. You can see the results of the same query here...

```
ID  Date                    SpeakerID
9   2005-03-24 00:00:00.000 3
10  2005-05-16 00:00:00.000 26
11  2005-10-24 00:00:00.000 55
12  2005-11-13 00:00:00.000 26
13  2006-01-10 00:00:00.000 1
14  2006-01-09 00:00:00.000 2
```

See how we now have a lecture with ID 10? If you look at the other two fields shown here, it's renumbered the IDs. This happened all the way through the table, so by the time we got to lecture with ID 2788 (fairly recent), it had been renumbered to 2760.

This happened on a couple of tables, and as you can imagine, has completely corrupted the entire database.

Anyone any idea how or why this happened? My first thought was that because I had renamed the primary key, which required SQL Server to drop and recreate the table, it had renumbered the IDs sequentially when reinserting the data. However, apart from the sheer stupidity of that idea, I couldn't reproduce it. I have renamed the primary key on the lectures table on the restored backup several times, and the numbering has not been affected. None of the other changes I did were remotely connected. They were just adding new columns, or of the type of changing varchar(1000) to varchar(max).

I really need to know how and why this happened, as I still need to make the changes. We've lost a few days' worth of data, as we didn't spot this problem straight away. I don't want that to happen again.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: How did you rename the column?  Through the GUI or via a script?

Comment: Sadly, I can't remember now. I wrote a script to do it, which I built whilst making changes on a locally installed copy of the database, but when I ran this on the real one, I had a couple of  errors, and had to do some of the update by hand. I can't remember which way the rename was done. However, I've since tried doing it both ways on the restored backup, and it worked fine both ways, so I'm baffled on that front.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you used a custom script since you can't rename a column that a constraint is based on. You need to drop the constraint first in such a case.

I do know that custom scripts that rename columns often do this by creating a new table with the same structure, copying the data over, removing original table, and finally renaming the new table. This is a perfectly legitimate strategy, especially with changes to multiple columns or large datasets that need to be processed partition-by-partition.

That said, that query there copying the data between the original table and the new new copy obviously needs to be manually updated for each change you're rolling out. I suspect an error there allowed the target table to recreate the values by means of `IDENTITY` constraint instead of using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT schema.table ON` and copying the old values over. Can you investigate the script you used?

Comment: I did use a script to modify the database, but the conversion wasn't anything as complex as copying the table. All I did was run sp_RENAME 'Lectures.LectureID', 'ID' , 'COLUMN' which did the job for me. I've tried this since, and it worked fine without renumbering the IDs. Mind you, I've since tried changing the name of the primary key via the GUI and that worked as well, so I have no idea what went wrong!